# Why is 'new int (*)[10]' wrong?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I tried this code:

```
auto p = new int (*)[10];
```

but I got error messeage:

```
test.cc:8:21: error: expected expression
        auto p = new int (*)[10];
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

I changed my code:

```
typedef int array[10];
auto p = new array *;
```

And then everything goes well.
Why is this?

Comment: perchance, did you try `auto p = new (int (*)[10]);` ?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: If that was really the only error message you got it kinda sucks, because it doesn't do much to identify the issue for you. What toolchain was that from anyway?

Comment: @WhozCraig Both GCC and Clang give similar such error messages. MSVC is even worse and just says `syntax error: ')'`. But the error is exactly correct (but maybe not easy to understand), there should be an expression after the unary `*` operator.

Comment: @user17732522 interesting. my clang (apple 1300) reports: "this operator is not allowed at this point;  parenthesize the preceding new expression" . must have gotten ahold of some special sauce.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's what nvcc says: https://godbolt.org/z/Yo1jbjoPM and ICC similarly: https://godbolt.org/z/bbqcfanYs

Comment: In modern C++ explicit use of `new` is a bad practice. In this case you should use `std::vector<int>`  or `std::array<int, 10>`.

Comment: new has its uses, particularly in polymorphism so I wouldn't call it bad practice.  in this case those container classes would indeed be more appropriate and clearer.

Answer (score 15):

For details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new.

Syntax for `new` without initializer is either

```
new (type)
```

or

```
new type
```

In the second case `type` may not contain parenthesis. This is also demonstrated in the above linked page:

> ```
> new int(*[10])();    // error: parsed as (new int) (*[10]) ()
> new (int (*[10])()); // okay: allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions
> ```

For your case that means:

```
auto p = new int (*)[10];     // error: parsed as (new int) ((*)[10])
auto p = new ( int (*)[10] ); // ok
```

When you use the alias, you can write

```
auto p = new array *;
```

because here `type` does not contain parenthesis.